# Wrapper around a class C++

Tags: c++, wrapper

suppose a C++ class has a constructor (among other constructors) of the form

```
Foo::Foo( FILE *fp ) { etc... }
```

Now I want create a wrapper class of the form

```
class WFoo {
      Foo::Foo A;
      Foo::Foo B;
 };
```

with constructor

```
WFoo::WFoo(FILE *fa, FILE *fb) {
      A(fa), B(fb);
}
```

What is wrong with the definition of WFoo?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't make any sense...

```
class WFoo {
      Foo::Foo A;
      Foo::Foo B;
 };
```

You mean...

```
class WFoo {
public:
      Foo A;
      Foo B;

      WFoo(FILE* fa, FILE* fb);
 };

WFoo::WFoo(FILE* fa, FILE* fb) :
    A(fa), B(fb)
{
}
```

Remember also that fields are initialized not in the order you read in the constructor but in the order they are declared in the class!

So...

```
#include <iostream>

struct XFoo
{
    XFoo(const char* s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
};

struct YBar
{
    XFoo a;
    XFoo b;

    YBar() : a("A"), b("B") {}
};

struct ZBar
{
    XFoo b;
    XFoo a;

    ZBar() : a("A"), b("B") {}
};


int main()
{
    YBar y;
    ZBar z;
    return 0;
}
```

will print out...

```
A
B
B
A
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an initializer list but the syntax is off. Try:

```
WFoo::WFoo(FILE* fa, FILE* fb) : A(fa), B(fb)
  {
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
WFoo::WFoo(FILE *fa, FILE *fb) : A(fa), B(fb) { ... }
```

And, unless `Foo` is in a namespace called `Foo` and `WFoo` is not:

```
class WFoo {
   Foo A;
   Foo B;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code you've posted is psudocode, then there is *nothing* wrong with the definition of `WFoo`.

If, on the other hand, the code you've posted is not intended to be psudocode, but actual code you'd try to compile & run, then here is what's wrong with `WFoo`:

1. You want `Foo A;` Not `Foo::Foo A` unless `Foo` is in a namespace called `Foo` (which would be bad)
2. There is no convert constructor declaration.
3. You aren't using the correct syntax for the initializer list.

This is what you want:

```
WFoo::WFoo(FILE* fa, FILE* fb)
:  A(fa), B(fb)
{
}
```

Note that the initializer list comes before the body of the constructor.